# How do I build mongodb with SSL support on saucy?

Tags: 13.10, ssl, mongodb

The mongodb packages in ubuntu do not contain SSL support (this is due to a restriction from 10gen, the makers of mongo).  However, you're supposed to be able to build it yourself... but the instructions on mongo's website don't seem to work for Saucy (because of a newer gcc), and aren't clear on all the steps to enable SSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the question mentioned, the [directions to build mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/) on 10gen's website aren't quite correct for newer versions of Ubuntu, and leave out details about SSL.

Here's what you do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y git-core build-essential scons libssl-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev 
git clone git://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git 
cd mongo 
git checkout r2.4.8
```

Obviously, replace the version here with whatever version you desire.

Be aware, there is a bug with the build of mongo, where it doesn't play happily with gcc 4.8 (which is what is in Saucy), see the bug report here - http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701324.

Luckily, in the bug report there is also a patch to fix it, so you need to apply that (it's just two lines): http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=14;filename=0008-ignore-unused-local-typedefs.patch;att=1;bug=701324

Now you can do the rest:

```
cd src
scons --ssl all 
sudo scons --ssl --prefix=/opt/mongo install
```

That's it. The build and install take a LONG time... approximately 30 minutes and 15 minutes respectively on my Haswell quad core i7 w/ SSD, so make sure you have something else to do while it chugs along in the background.

Comment: +1 for the full build instructions - much better than the official version! The build will also require a lot of memory (> 2GB) and disk space (the full final build takes up 25GB). Worth considering if running in a resource constrained environment, such as a micro VPS on AWS.

Comment: p.s. you can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Hello I have tried your approach. I was expecting to see .deb packages